# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

Tags: neo4j

I’m running Neo4J 2.2.1 with 150G heap space on a box with 240G. I set the `neo4j.neostore.nodestore.dbms.pagecache.memory` to 60G (slightly less than 75% of remaining system memory as recommended). However, when I startup I get an error that the system can’t start because I’m trying to allocate an array whose size exceeds the maximum allowed size.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: 64bit. 1.8.x. If I use the pre 2.2.x settings of:
neo4j.neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory
neo4j.neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory
neo4j.neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory
neo4j.neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory

Then with tweaking I can get it to come up. however, those are deprecated so I'm trying to use the new correct settings.

Comment: Can you include the stacktrace

Comment: There is no meaningful stack track:
Error creating bean with name 'neoService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit

Comment: Further testing indicates that it is either the node_cache_array_fraction or the relationship_cache_array_faction (probably both) that is causing the problem. It is supposed to default to 1%. On an 150G heap that should be 1.5G. 
Explicitly setting node_cache_size and relationship_cache_size seems to address this although it is far from ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further testing indicates that it is either the `node_cache_array_fraction` and the `relationship_cache_array_faction` are causing the problem. It is supposed to default to 1%. On an 150G heap that should be 1.5G. However the array size being generated is too long.
Explicitly setting `node_cache_size` and `relationship_cache_size` seems to address this although it is far from ideal.

Comment: In Neo4j 2.3 the object cache gets removed due to further improvements of the off-heap pagecache. I guess this will be the definitive solution for you. Note that Neo4j 2.3 M01 is out there at the time of writing this. Data migrations between milestones are generally not supported.